# Selector for Multi Choice ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, selector

I can't highlight a multichoice list view with custom adapter in android. The activated and pressed state works just fine. What I want is when the user taps on an item it should be highlighted.

my **new_list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
</selector>
```

in the above xml, the states for "activated" and "pressed" are working but not "selected".

In my **listview_item.xml** I set the background to selector as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/new_list_selector">
<!--list items goes here-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

I define my list view like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/masterContainer">
<ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/friendViewList" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the activated state when I tap and hold a list item. The pressed state works when I tap the list item. I want it to be highlighted when the user taps the item. Can someone help me out on this? Thanks for any input in advance.

PS: I prefer xml solution over coding. I have also tried selector with `state_focused` set to `true` with no luck

Comment: Then don't set it as layout's background. Instead make it the background for the item present in it.

Comment: thanks for the input. That is indeed the layout for the items presented in the listview. This layout contains an image and two text views which I removed it for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
<ImageView 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/new_list_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will set the selector on ImageView. You can also do it with your two TexTviews.

Comment: I'll definitely try this out and get back to you

Comment: just tried it out. Unfortunately, this did not fix my issue

Comment: You tried it with ImageView? Are you dynamically overriding an ImageView's background?

Comment: Yes, I tried with image view and the textviews. I am not overriding imageview anywhere. I am just setting the image in my custom adapter.

Comment: It should work. upload the screenshot of your activity.

Comment: sorry for the delay. here is the pic for when the list is activated http://bayimg.com/AaaddaaGk and here is in normal state http://bayimg.com/AaAdgaAgk